# transform a lits of lists into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have  the following `list of lists`:

```
list1=[['remote attackers',
  'attacker',
  'malicious code',
  'malicious user',
  'attack'],
 ['greenbone vulnerability manager',
  'web application abuses',
  'web management interfaces',
  'application'],
 ['ftp servers', 'server', 'tcp', 'application', 'rpc']]
```

I want to cast this `list of lists` into a `dataframe`:

```
clusters
0 remote attackers,attacker,malicious code,malicious user,attack
1 greenbone vulnerability manager, web application abuses, web management interfaces, application
2 ftp servers,server,tcp,application,rpc
```

I tried to flat the `list` but this did not output the expected outcome.

Also, I tried to iterate over the `list of lists` and append each `list` into a `dataframe` but this is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clusters': list1})
```

output:

```
                                            clusters
0  [remote attackers, attacker, malicious code, m...
1  [greenbone vulnerability manager, web applicat...
2       [ftp servers, server, tcp, application, rpc]
```

If you want concatenated strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clusters': map(','.join, list1)})
```

output:

```
                                            clusters
0  remote attackers,attacker,malicious code,malic...
1  greenbone vulnerability manager,web applicatio...
2             ftp servers,server,tcp,application,rpc
```